# Boolean array as condition on float array in Eigen in AVX

Tags: c++, eigen, simd, avx2

**Context:**

I decided to get started with Eigen's fixed length Arrays (`Eigen::Array<float, 8, 1>`) to implement templated functions that allow to instantiate them for both scalar `float` and the SIMD (AVX2 ymm-register) float vectors. For example:

```cpp
template<typename T> inline T add(const T &a, const T &b) { return a + b; }
```

Now, when using `typedef Array<float, 8, 1> f32x8`, I can use this function in two ways:

```cpp
f32x8 a, b;
f32x8 sum = add(a, b);
```

The reason why, is because now I have a single implementation that works for both `float` and `f32x8` AND leverages SIMD instructions, and this literally compiles to a single instruction `vaddps`, which is what I need.

**Question:**

Now, when making a function like this (using `typedef Eigen::Array<bool, 8, 1> boolx8`):

```cpp
f32x8 a, b, c;
boolx8 m1 = a < b;
boolx8 m2 = b < c;
boolx8 m3 = m1 && m2;
```

Eigen generates code that does everything in a scalar way (unpacks the values, makes a loop, does the logic one element at a time), because the definition of `bool` is such that sizeof(bool) = 1, and thus `sizeof(boolx8) = 8`. This makes the use of AVX2 instructions seemingly impossible as they store their results as a bitmask in the `ymm`-registers themselves too, which clearly is incompatible with the `sizeof(boolx8) = 8` requirement.

Is there away in Eigen to have code similar to what I posted, but have it use AVX2 instructions using `ymm` masks, such as `vcmpgtps`. I would assume we need a different datatype for the `boolx8` definition that IS compatible with Eigen.

**Update:**

In `Eigen/src/Core/arch/AVX2/PacketMath.h` at line 584, there is this definition:

```cpp
template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE
Packet8f pcmp_le(const Packet8f& a, const Packet8f& b) {
  return _mm256_cmp_ps(a,b,_CMP_LE_OQ);
}
```

So, clearly the result should somehow be again `f32x8`.

Comment: Yeah, this is easy to manually vectorize with AVX2, 2x `vcmpgtps` + `vandps` plus some shuffles to pack things from dword to byte elements, like `vpacksswd` to pack within halves / `vpermq` to move data across lanes, so you have 8 words in the low 128 bits. Then `vpacksswb` and your boolx8 is the low qword.  Or to use `vpmovmskb` to get 4 bits from each float, and widen nibbles to bytes perhaps, if you have fast BMI2 `pdep`.  Oh, I guess maybe a `pabsb` to turn `-1` into `0x01` bytes.

Comment: So the question is how you can tell Eigen about manually vectorized stuff, like with `__m256i` types and `_mm256_packs_epi16`.    Of course both of these are pretty inefficient if you actually want a whole array of bools from more than 8 floats; you want to shuffle 4 vandps results down to 1 vec.  Or depending what you're doing, use 4 bytes per mask element (small temporary arrays that stay hot in cache, or a single vector wide that you use to mask a store).  e.g. if you want to use them as actual masks to control / blend / maskstore / maskload other vectors.

Comment: Does Eigen have any mask types that solve this for you, hopefully which can use bitmasks instead of bool arrays when compiling for AVX-512?

Comment: Exactly: I was hoping to find some mask type, but didn't yet.

Comment: As far as I can tell Eigen has very few facilities for boolean arrays. Since masks etc. are very much platform-dependent, abstractions are tough to design (AVX2 masks vs. AVX512 mask registers would be a good example). So Eigen mostly generates plain C++ code for this and leaves the rest to the compiler. Basically, boolean arrays are not designed to be stored but only used as intermediates for ```select()```

Comment: Related issue: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/97 -- at the moment you can only hope for your compiler to auto-vectorize corresponding Eigen-expressions.